# Remove PROPERTYNAME list on final url

Tags: geoserver

I have setup my WFS data store and published a layer in Geoserver.
Nothing is displayed in the map div when I use the preview with openlayers option and further to this when I click on the map div where I would expect a html table of info I get a file download which is xml text of an error.

The error then displays the response it got from the WFS telling me "Unable to respond to request"

The url for the store ends with a link to a .wfsx file i.e. my.domain.com/my_map.wsfx

The error also displays a "final URL" with a lot of additional parameters appended to the store's url.

I have taken this final url and put it in a browser and sure enough I get the error message "Unable to respond to request"
The interesting thing is that if I remove the "PROPERTYNAME" parameter from the url and input that into the browser I get the results I want.

Geoserver is appending every single property listed against this layer against the parameter PROPERTYNAME in the url is generates when requesting data from the WFS.

Is there anyway I can configure this store or layer to not use the PROPERTYNAME parameter?

Comment: is this a cascaded layer?

Comment: please turn the logging level up to developer and then check the log file

Comment: Yeah it is a cascaded layer.

Using the url geoserver generates in the background and lists as the "final url" I can hit the wfs and get a valid response but only if I remove the massive list of properties it appends to the PROPERTYNAME parameter in the url.

How can I instruct geoserver to not append it to any urls it is generating?

Comment: please add some details of the remote WFS - wfs version etc, preferably the url

Comment: Unfortunately I have had to remove the actual link as it require a username and password to get to and is not publicly available, I realise this does not help.
The address geoserver is generating and showing in the error has an additional parapameter on the url "PROPERTYNAME=[a long list if all available properties]" and when this is on there it ceases to work and errors, when I remove it and try it manually I get some nice feature data back with no error

Comment: http://www.address.com/web-feature-service/file.wfsx?BBOX=xxx&Filter%3E&TYPENAME=xxx&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fgml%2Bxml%3B+version%3D3.2&VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS

Comment: There is nothing wrong per se with listing all the properties and every compliant WFS server must understand the request. However, the request may come so big that it exceeds the limits which are configured on the http server. Debug by taking the request and making the propertyname list shorter.

Comment: Thanks, yeah tried making it shorter, but that fails with the same error:Unable to respond to request. It is only when I remove the PROPERTYNAME altogether that it works. Mayhaps there is nothing can be done on my end and I need to contact the wfs vendor.

Comment: is this wfs 2.0 or 1.1 or 1.0?

Comment: Version 2.0
What is frustrating is that it works fine in qGIS.